# how to set a counter in a stateful widget from outside the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget that is 2 counter buttons and a counter display between them.

```
class OneCounterTwoBulbs extends StatefulWidget {
  final int counter;
  const OneCounterTwoBulbs({Key? key, required this.counter}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OneCounterTwoBulbs> createState() => _OneCounterTwoBulbsState();
}

class _OneCounterTwoBulbsState extends State<OneCounterTwoBulbs> {
  int friendlyCounter = 0;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CounterAndButtons(
                    minusButton: Expanded(
                      child: PlusMinusButton(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (friendlyCounter > 0) {
                              friendlyCounter--;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                        bgColor: kBlueGrey900,
                        iconColor: kWhite,
                      ),
                    ),
                    counter: Counter(counter: '$friendlyCounter'),
                    plusButton: Expanded(
                      child: PlusMinusButton(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            friendlyCounter++;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                        bgColor: kBlueGrey900,
                        iconColor: kWhite,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I'm using this widget multiple times throughout my app and I need to be able to specify what number the counter should start at from the parent stateful widget.

how do I make widget.counter = friendlyCounter inside the widget?

thanks so much

Comment: Can you simplify the widget by removing custom widget

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? remove the CounterAndButtons Widget?

Comment: yes you can remove those and use basic widget to reproduce the same error .

Comment: it's not an error. Basically, when I call the OneCounterTwoBulbs widget in a parent widget, I want to be able to set what number the friendly counter will start at

Comment: you like to reuse this widget multiple time maintaining the state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameter is not updating because with setState it will only rebuild the parameter/state/variables that are in the same screen/class widget where the setState is called so you have to raise your parameter to the parent screen then pass it to the child with constructor and create a constructor in your child for function onTap for example then in the parent screen you use that onTap and called setState inside

Comment: thanks so much. could you do it with initstate? when the widget is inserted into the tree?

Comment: If you are going to modify the state of a widget from outside, I recommend to use a state managment

Comment: The key is you have to use the setState in the screen where your valu are going to change or update, btw don't forget to mark the answer as an answer :)